# How to delete a Prototype object with a pointer to it?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, singly-linked-list

I have been coding a singly linked list in JavaScript.
My structure is:

```
function node(x)
{
    this.x=x;
    this.next=null;
}

function sl()  //sl-singly linked list
{
    this.first=null;
    this.l=0; //length of list
}
```

Where I get the trouble :

Delete Last Method :

```
sl.prototype.deletel=function()
{
    if(this.first)
    {
        var t=this.first;
        while(t.next)
            t=t.next;
        if(t)
            t=null;
    }
}
```

Even though I made the pointer to the last element null, still  Last node gets printed.
I have attached the working snippet. Operations:

Generate List :01234
Invoking Delete Last...
Expected Output : 0123
What I get      : 01234

```js
function node(x)
{
 this.x=x;
 this.next=null;
}

function sl()
{
 this.l=0;
 this.first=null;
}

sl.prototype.insertl=function(x)
{
 var newnode=new node(x);
 var t=this.first;
 if(!this.first)
  this.first=newnode;
 else
 {
  while(t.next)
   t=t.next;
  t.next=newnode;
 }
 l++;
}

sl.prototype.deletel=function()
{
 if(this.first)
 {
  var t=this.first;
  while(t.next)
   t=t.next;
  if(t)
   t=null;
 }
}

sl.prototype.console=function()
{
 var t=this.first;
 while(t)
 {
  document.write(t.x);
  t=t.next;
 }
}
sl();
sl.prototype.insertl(0);
sl.prototype.insertl(1);
sl.prototype.insertl(2);
sl.prototype.insertl(3);
sl.prototype.insertl(4);
sl.prototype.deletel();
alert("check");
sl.prototype.console();
```

Comment: Looking at your code you are making the pointer to the last element (fifth) `null` but the `t.next` of the fourth element still holds the value 4 which is printed in the console function.

Comment: Let me say like this , t.x=0 , t1.x=1 , .. , t4.x=4 , and this implies t3.next=t4 , now I made t4=null therefore t3.next=t4 implies t3.next=null (since t4=null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Even though I made the pointer to the last element null

No, you did not. There are no pointers in JavaScript. `t` is nothing but a local variable, which you did set to `null` indeed, but you did not alter a property of any object. You do however need to nullify the `.next` property of the second-to-last node:

```
sl.prototype.deletel = function() {
    var t = this.first;
    if (t) {
        var n = t.next;
        if (n) {
            while (n.next) {
                t = n;
                n = n.next;
            }
            t.next = null; // remove last node from second-to-last
        } else {
            this.first = null; // remove last node from list
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I had worked this out already :) , but now I got cleared why my former code did not work.So .next is of reference type and t is just local. Got it :)